# error with signature token when filling a typeform

Tags: python, request, typeform

I'm learning Python and I'm trying to fill a type form using Python requests, however I get this error response:

```
{"code":"VALIDATION_ERROR","description":"The provided body is malformed.","details":[{"code":"INVALID_PAYLOAD","description":"signature mismatch","in":"BODY","field":".signature"}]}
```

However, when I put the `token.text` value manually in `data` it works. I can't get it working when adding the token programmatically to the payload, even tried with `str()` and it's not working.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import time

epochTime = int(time.time())
token = requests.get("https://mehdikhireddine.typeform.com/app/form/result/token/OcotDC/default")
final = token.text
print(token.text)
data = { "signature": final,
         "form_id": "OcotDC",
         "landed_at": epochTime,""
         "answers": [
        {
            "field": {
                "id": "nDoisfzMsrBP",
                "type": "short_text"
            },
            "type": "text",
            "text": "mehdilemoi"
        },
        {
            "field": {
                "id": "iCW4s6Fc37OL",
                "type": "legal"
            },
            "type": "boolean",
            "boolean": True
        }

    ]
}
r = requests.post("https://mehdikhireddine.typeform.com/app/form/submit/OcotDC", json=data)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error. Could you share the traceback?

Comment: sorry, how do i share it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue arises if you store the `epochTime` before getting the `token` from the HTTPS response, presumably because the server then fails to match the signature and time, resulting in `"signature mismatch"`.

You can fix this by taking the current time *after* the `token` response has been received, i.e.:

```
token = requests.get("https://mehdikhireddine.typeform.com/app/form/result/token/OcotDC/default")
epochTime = int(time.time())
```

Output:

```
{"message":"success"}
```

Note that this may still intermittently fail if too much time elapses between getting the response and getting the `epochTime`.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't work now. Please tell me how to get a token from typeform now?